# How do you combine PHP and Python on webserver or localhost?

Tags: python, php, localhost, webserver

So let's say I want to build a simple python script that BASE45 encodes a string(I know that you can do that with PHP but for the purpose of learning how to combine both).

Then I have an HTML form with one input, when submit button is clicked I want to send that input to that python script and return the BASE45 encoded string of that input.

How can it be done in localhost and on a webserver?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I have an HTML form with one input, when submit button is clicked I want to send that input to that python script and return the BASE45 encoded string of that input."_ Ok... so where does PHP come into play in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> Then I have an HTML form with one input, when submit button is clicked
> I want to send that input to that python script and return the BASE45
> encoded string of that input.

This sound like task when will comes CGI, `python`'s standard library has [`cgi`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html) module which is destined for writing python script to be used in CGI server.